# Vimeo API - Cannot request from metadata connections URI

Tags: reactjs, axios, request, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am currently using axios with the Vimeo API.

I'm confused on why I can request https://api.vimeo.com/tags/customtag and get a response showing that there is indeed 35 videos.

```
"metadata": {
    "connections": {
        "videos": {
            "uri": "/tags/customtag/videos",
            "options": [
                "GET"
            ],
            "total": 35
        }
    }
},
```

But then if I make another request using the uri in the previous request like https://api.vimeo.com/tags/customtag/videos it is empty:

```
{
"total": 0,
"page": 1,
"per_page": 25,
"paging": {
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "first": "/tags/customtag/videos?page=1",
    "last": "/tags/customtag/videos?page=1"
},
"data": []
```

}

These videos are indeed hidden off of Vimeo for competitor confidentiality purposes. Is there a way to access this data and keep it private?

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

This is a bug on the Response, the tags do not return private videos.

You can fetch your private videos using your videos endpoint,

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_videos

You can use the `filter_tag` query parameter, so for example

GET /me/videos?filter_tag=customtag should do what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried this solution and it will just return all of the videos.. as if its ignoring filter_tag query parameter. Looks like I'll have to wait until this bug is fixed.

Comment: You might check again using the `filter_tag` parameter on get_videos, this should be addressed now.